# MongoDb query $nin can't read from document array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have given a collection named `votes` containing documents based on this design:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c000000000000001"),
    "timestamp" : 1456441690,
    "filename" : "42598295724057245724579",
    "phoneNumber" : 49123456789,
    "phoneNumberVotes" : [ 
        49123456783,
        49123456784
    ]
}
```

The `phoneNumberVotes` array can be empty.

I am trying to perform this query:

```
db.getCollection('votes').find
(
    {
        $and:[
            { phoneNumber: { $ne: 49123456789}},
            { phoneNumber: { $nin: phoneNumberVotes }}
        ]
    },
    { timestamp: 1, filename: 1, phoneNumber: 1, phoneNumberVotes: 1}
)
```

But this doesn't work. When I try to "manually" create an array within the query it works e.g.:

```
db.getCollection('votes').find
(
    {
        $and:[
            { phoneNumber: { $ne: 49123456789}},
            { phoneNumber: { $nin: [49123456783,49123456784] }}
        ]
    },
    { timestamp: 1, filename: 1, phoneNumber: 1, phoneNumberVotes: 1}
)
```

What is wrong with the method I try to use? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare fields directly. There is a difference between `<field>` and `<value>` in the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/).

In your case you need to use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator to execute javascript:

```
db.votes.find
(
    {
        phoneNumberVotes:{$exists:true},
        phoneNumber:{$exists:true, $ne:"49123456789"},
        $where: 'this.phoneNumberVotes.indexOf(this.phoneNumber) < 0'
    },
    { timestamp: 1, filename: 1, phoneNumber: 1, phoneNumberVotes: 1}
)
```

It works with scalar values.

You are using numbers, which are [NumberLong](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong). There is an [old bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1672) related to object comparison, so you need to convert phone numbers to strings:

```
db.votes.find
(
    {
        phoneNumberVotes:{$exists:true},
        phoneNumber:{$exists:true, $ne:49123456789},
        $where: 'this.phoneNumberVotes.map(function(n){return n + ""}).indexOf(this.phoneNumber + "") < 0'
    },
    { timestamp: 1, filename: 1, phoneNumber: 1, phoneNumberVotes: 1}
)
```

It may be quite slow, so it may worth to convert phone numbers to strings in the database, rather than do it runtime.